# The Seder of Tomchei Temimim

Tags: history, chabad, yeshiva-school

What was the seder (schedule) of Yeshiva Tomchei Temimim (the one instituted by [the Rebbe Reshab](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sholom_Dovber_Schneersohn)).

[I see the *current* schedule on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tomchei_Temimim#Typical_schedule):

> 7:30 a.m. - Chasidus - Hasidic philosophy (in some locales such as Israel and Australia first classes start at 7:00 a.m.)
>   9:00 a.m. - preparation for prayers, including Mikveh immersion (for those who didn't do so before 7:30 a.m.)
>   9:15 a.m. - Shacharis - Morning prayers
>   10:15 a.m. - Breakfast
>   11:00 a.m. - Iyun - Morning in depth Talmud study
>   1:00 p.m. - shiur (lecture) - more advanced students receive lectures less often
>   2:00 p.m. - Mincha - afternoon prayers
>   2:15 p.m. - Lunch and break period
>   3:30 p.m. - Afternoon Talmud, including review of morning study and less in-depth Talmudic study known as girsa
>   6:00 p.m. - Halacha study
>   7:00 p.m. - Dinner and break period
>   8:00 p.m. - Night Seder: Hasidic philosophy - Chasidus
>   9:30 p.m. - Ma'ariv - Evening prayers
>   9:45 p.m. - Seder Sichos - unofficial study of Rabbi M. M. Schneerson's public addresses

But this is not the same one made by the Rebbe Reshab, because they obviously wouldn't learn Sichos from Rabbi M. M. Schneerson.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Chassidus twice a day - From 7:30 am for 2 hours (but better to start at 7 and learn for 2.5 hours) and  9-11 pm (but those who needed to go to sleep early could come and leave early).

See details in Kuntres Etz Hachaim (Written by the rebbe Rashab for the talmidim) [pg 51-52 chapter 25](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=15741&st=&pgnum=54&hilite=)